# POST параметры по ссылки

Tags: php

Скрипт a.php принимает два параметра, как если просто обратится по ссылки в запросе написать значение данных параметров? хочу протестировать как работают запросы.

https://домен//100/a.php

```
$k=$_POST['num']; 
$k2=$_POST['num2'];
```

Comment: взять по $_GET, а не $_POST

Comment: То есть никак? нельзя?

Comment: Если нужен именно $_POST, то для этих целей есть инструменты типа Postman

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать, только зачем?)

a.php

```
if (isset($_POST['sumbit'])) { // если была нажата кнопка
    $k = $_POST['num'];
    $k2 = $_POST['num2'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['num']) and isset($_GET['num2'])) { /если GET запрос
    $k = $_GET['num'];
    $k2 = $_GET['num2'];
} else {
    $k = null;
    $k2 = null;
}
    
echo 'num = '.$k.' num2 = '.$k2;
```

строка будет выглядеть так https://домен//100/a.php?num=1&num2=2